# What is an equivalent condition to $\sigma f = f\sigma \ \forall \sigma \in S_X,$ where $f: X \to X$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory, functions

Let $f: X \to X$ be a map of sets and $\text{Sym}_X$ be the group of permutations of $X$.  Then if $f$ commutes with every permutation $\sigma \in \text{Sym}_X$ what else can we say about $f$?

- We can say that if $|X| \gt 1$, then $f$ is not constant since if:
  $X= \{a,b,c\dots\}$ and $f(X) = c$.  Then $\sigma(c) = \sigma f(x) = f \sigma(x) = c$ is not true for all $\sigma \in \text{Sym}_X$, clearly.

**Motivated by this question:**
Precisely when are the $V_f(G)=\{x \in X: gf(x) = fg(x), \forall g \in G \}, G\leqslant \text{Sym}_X$ a basis for a topology on $X$?

Since $V_f(\text{id}) = X$ and $V_f(G) \cap V_f(H) = V_f(G \cap H)$ so that unions of $V_f$'s are open sets precisely when $V_f(K) = \varnothing$, which would happen when $gf(x) \neq fg(x)$ for some $(g,x) \in K \times X$.

Comment: The identity function is clearly an option. If $|X|>2$, then $f$ cannot be a non-trivial bijection, i.e. a permutation, because no such function commutes with all other permutations.

Comment: But, if $f$ is not surjective, I guess, it would not commute with a permutation that mixes up elements in its range with its non-range.

Comment: @Berci That leaves surjective, non-injective functions.

Comment: @Arthur Therefore $X$ cannot be finite.

Comment: You are also going to run into some troubles if the map is not injective. Say $f(x)=f(y)=c$ for some $x\neq y$. Then, for any $\sigma$ satisfying $\sigma(x)=y$ you get $\sigma(c)=c$. . .

Comment: @David Hill Therefore $V_f(\text{Sym}_X) = \varnothing$ and the proof is complete, for $|X| \gt 2$.  $V_f$'s always form a topology.  What is the name of this topology?